# How to log user name with elasticsearch jetty plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, jetty, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elasticsearch  jetty plugin in order to log queries , what I want to do is to add just a new log to my actuals logs, that is " the name of the user who made the query".

Can you please tell me if this is possible? And how I can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can log the remoteUser using the "json" option of jetty plugin